# Хранить 8 bool в одном

Tags: c++, c, память

Однажды читал статью в которой засказывали что тип данных bool занимает в памяти в 8 больше чем ему нужно для хранения 0/1. Сейчас вспомнил об этом и захотел сделать, к сожалению ту статью найти уже не могу и чего-то похожего тоже. Посидел подолбался с побитовым сдвигом и другими такими операциями и начал сомневаться что такое вообще возможно. Если кто-нибудь знает или раскажите или киньте ссылку на источник.

Comment: Так а зачем? ;)

Comment: Да можно, просто хранить в одном `unsigned char` 8 штук. См. `vector<bool>`, а также `bitset`, раз у вас метка C++...

Comment: bitset не плохой вариант но я хочу посмотреть имено на простую реализацию с bool или uchar

Comment: `if (c & (1 << bit_num)) { // бит bit_num установлен }`  `c |= (1 << bit_num); // установить бит bit_num` `c &= ~(1 << bit_num); // сбросить бит bit_num` / Все это совершенно обычно для низкоуровневого (приближенного к реальной работе CPU) программирования

Comment: Можно по-подробне что вы здесь сделали и как оно работает?

Comment: c ^= (1 << bit_num); // изменить бит bit_num

Comment: @AlbionMuz, если обращаетесь к кому-нибудь тут и хотите, чтобы он получил notification, то пишите в начале комментария `@nick`. Поподробнее? Прочтите для начала несколько страниц, например, в k&r, если потом останутся конкретные вопросы, задавайте их.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В языке С для работы с битами внутри байта существует более простая возможность-  битовые *union* типы. Ими очень часто пользуются разаработчики по для "железа", где нужно читать битовые поля из регистров и т.д.

Подробно можете об этом прочитать в разделе "Битовые поля" книги Подбельского В.В. "Программирование на языке С", стр 320. Элементарный пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Расписываем битовые поля 16-битного регистра
union bit_register {
    unsigned short bit0:1; // Самый младший бит слова
    unsigned short bit1:1; // Следующий бит слова
    unsigned short f_1:10; // Поле из 10 бит
    unsigned short filler:4; // Оставшиеся 4 бита
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    union bit_register r1, r2;

    r1.bit0 = 1;
    r2.bit1 = r1.bit0;
    printf("Битовое поле второго регистра: %d\n", r2.bit1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Так для того, что вы желаете, существуют битовые флаги.

Например, вместо следующего кода:

```
bool bFlag1 = true;
bool bFlag2 = false;
bool bFlag3 = true;
....
if (bFlag1) {...}
if (!bFlag2) {...}
if (bFlag2 || bFlag3) {...}
```

Можете использовать этот, эквивалентный, но с упакованными в один байт bool'ами:

```
#define FLAG1 1
#define FLAG2 2
#define FLAG3 4

char cFlags = FLAG1 | FLAG3;
...
if (cFlags&FLAG1) {...}
if (!(cFlags&FLAG2)) {...}
if (cFlags&(FLAG2|FLAG3)) {...}
```